# Which choice leads to performance maximization?

Tags: performance

Suppose you are given the task of improving the performance of a program consisting of three parts. Part A requires 20% of the overall run time, part B requires 30%, and part C requires 50%.

You determine that for $1000 you could either speed up part B by a factor of 3.0 or part C by a factor of 1.5. Which choice would maximize performance?

I think if you speed up part B by a factor of 3.0, then you only spend 10% of your time on that, saving 20% time. But if you speed up part C by a factor of 1.5, then you spend 25% time and save 25% time.

So is speed up part C the right answer since you save 25% vs 20%?

I feel like I'm not getting these numbers right. If I'm not could someone show how to compute this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple optimization problem (not in a sense of optimizing your program's code, but in the sense of finding an optimum point of a mathematical function).

You'd have to define a [utility function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_function) which models the trade-off between time (and $) spent working on the task (*the cost*), and the benefit of the work (*the gain*, which attemps to describe performence boost in $ terms).

[If you want to make things more complicated, you can add probabilities (if the actual performence boost is not known in advance). To make things even more complicated, you may add a cost-term (*penalty*) describing the cost of the uncertainty in your probability estimation (think of the last two as the expected value and the variance of your *gain* and *cost* random variables).]

The intuition is that the utility function models your "happiness level" of the situation.

Once you have your utility function, all that is left is finding the maximum point, which can be done in various ways (analytically, numerically, ...).

Without such a utility function, describing the trade-off between cost and gain, you can't have a well-defined answer to your question.

Comment: So would my utility function be something like 1 = 0.2A + 0.3B + 0.5C? Where A, B, and C are all 1 to begin with or something?